# How could the Borg be patrolling the border of fluidic space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

In "Unimatrix Zero", Axom says he's on a scout ship patrolling the border of fluidic space.

I thought that fluidic space was in another dimension/ parallel universe and can only be entered through a quantum singularity. How can there be a border of fluidic space?

Comment: Presumably there are regions of space that are easier to "poke through" into other realms. This would qualify as a border.

Comment: as richard says, its most likely a part where fluidic space is "close" enough to our space for crossing between the 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that having an entire universe filled with fluid would be a logical impossibility, this strongly implies that while Fluidic space exists in a different subspace realm, it almost certaintly has a *physical* border within our own space. There may also be areas of space where it's easier to poke a hole into Fluidic space in both the Delta and Beta Quadrants.

[image]

Since Species 8472 are known to be indigenous to Fluidic Space, it seem most likely that if they were to try to get back into our own space, they would emerge within this region (or regions), hence there being a *border* (or borders) for the Borg to patrol.

Comment: "Given that having an entire universe filled with fluid would be a logical impossibility ..." If you think about gravitational collaps, it could work out if the universe is curved (you fly in one direction and end up at your starting Point). Then the gravitational effect of all the evenly distributed fluid could cancel out. If the universe is small enough it might be even stable and neither expanding nor imploding. But I'm no scientist.

Comment: @Hothie - I'm also no scientist, but I'm reasonably sure that any substance that was gloopy enough to become an observable fluid would be many trillions of times denser than the stuff that stars are made of. Since the fluid isn't evenly distributed (as evidenced by all the explosions and whatnot), then the formation of gravitational knots, eddies and ultimately stars and collapsars would seem almost inevitable.

Comment: Who ever said that the fluid had (gravitational) mass?

Comment: @OrangeDog - No-one, but neither did anyone comment that fluid space is bizarrely without gravity. I'm thinking that that would have been worthy of some conversation.

Comment: The vacuum of our space doesn't "have" gravity either.

Comment: @OrangeDog - It would do if it was filled with fluid.

Comment: And again, not if the fluid didn't have mass. Our space is not filled with vacuum, it is a vacuum. Fluidic space is not filled with fluid, it is a fluid.

Comment: @OrangeDog - It sounds like you want to ask a separate question :-)

Comment: @OrangeDog: Something without mass wouldn't have inertia, friction or viscosiy, so I don't see how it could be a fluid.

Comment: Use your imaginations. It doesn't have to have gravitational mass for any of those things. It's a different universe.