# Does a map exist that shows Star Trek civilizations/worlds in great detail?

Tags: star-trek

There's a related question which asks whether a map exists that shows where the various humanoid societies are located. That's fine, but is there a map of the galaxy that shows all canon civilizations/beings, and not merely humanoid ones/common ones?

My original question was going to ask where Metron space is, and how close it is to Organia. But then I wondered about Nagilum, and if its void is close to Metron space, or Organia, or the Edo god, etc. I realize that Nagilum is located in the Morgana Quadrant, but that doesn't say much.

Also, there are a lot of powerful physical beings from TOS, such as the Providers ("The Gamesters of Triskelion"), Flint, Apollo, etc. I don't know that the aforementioned map has the planets of these beings labeled. I'm inclined to say that it doesn't.

Comment: There are several answers here which show maps of the entire galaxy ([this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7294/4495) has a 2500x2000 map), so how large do you need it to be?

Comment: The answer to this is "Star Trek Star Charts: The Complete Atlas of Star Trek"

Comment: I've always hated the late TNG era maps that put Cardassia on the opposite side of the Federation from the Klingons and Romulans.  DS9 doesn't make sense unless all 4 share borders.  In a 3 dimensional Galaxy map I'd put Cardassian territory above or below some overlap with the Federation and Klingons such that there's room for expansion but it's always disputed. And sharing a border with the Romulans enough for political intrigue.  I'd speculate they have a history of tipping the balance of power in the Beta Quadrant - which would be consistent with how they joined the Dominion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I am aware, no *single* map exists that shows the locations of every planet and space-borne entity mentioned in Star Trek. Even the truly excellent [**Star Trek: Star Charts - The Complete Atlas of Star Trek**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) lacks the kind of granular detail you're describing. By the same token, its spiritual successor; [**Stellar Cartography: The Starfleet Reference Library**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stellar_Cartography:_The_Starfleet_Reference_Library) contains an impressive level of detail but is still relatively incomplete.

[image]

You might also be interested in the "[**Star Trek Map Search**](http://www.startrekmap.com/search.html)" facility offered by www.startrekmap.com. While it isn't a *complete* record of all of the places mentioned in the show (for example the Morgana Quadrant where Nagilum lives doesn't appear), it's probably the most comprehensive resource you're going to find on the subject.

Comment: Do you have the map you have uploaded in better quality? Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg - You might try this one; http://www.chartgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/star-trek-map1.jpeg