# How far is Skaro from Earth?

Tags: doctor-who

In Genesis of the Daleks, Skaro was a planet in the "Seventh Galaxy", is this the same Galaxy as we are in and if so, how near are we?

More generally, like in the [Star Trek universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132670/does-a-map-exist-that-shows-star-trek-civilizations-worlds-in-great-detail?rq=1), is there a map of the relative positions of the known planets (TV only) in the Dr Who (which is possibly more difficult because of the problem of time) universe; for example, Gallifrey, Draconia, Mira, Kembel (I'm sure in the [Dalek's Master Plan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Daleks%27_Master_Plan_(TV_story)) it was commented "Mira is nearer Kembel than Earth) ...?

Comment: It’s far. Like, rilly *rilly* far.

Comment: I suppose [Galaxy 4](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_4_(TV_story)) is about half-way (hope that helps).

Comment: The only reasonable figure I've come up with is from Terror of the Autons, where  the Time Lord warning the Doctor about the Master says he has travelled about 29,000 light years (this is often taken to be in a direction that would place Gallifrey near the centre of the Milky Way). From the Dalek Master Plan: the various planets mentioned are Kembel, Desperus, Earth and Mira. Given that Desperus is the solar system's prison planet and "Mira is nearer Kembel than Earth" presumably all these planets are reasonably close to each other. As well, the Daleks ally themselves with the outer galaxies.

Comment: Galaxy 4 was the story before "Mission to the Unknown".

Comment: Finally, from the Frontier of Space "The TARDIS arrives in the year 2540 on board an Earth spaceship, which then comes under attack . The crew perceive the Doctor, Jo and the attackers as Draconians, whose empire currently rivals Earth's for control of the galaxy", "the Ogron planet (on the remote fringes of the Milky Way galaxy) and routes in between". This may suggests that Draconia is in the Milky Way and so also is Spiridon (why put you army of Daleks too far away).

Comment: The location of Skaro seems to have a mixed and confusing history, see https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Skaro

Answer (score 5):

**Skaro is not in our Milky Way galaxy and is located in the Seventh Galaxy aproximately 480 million light years away from Earth.**

In Genesis of the Daleks (1975) it is stated that Skaro is situated in the "Seventh Galaxy" and that, according to the Kaleds,  Skaro was the only planet capable of supporting life in all of the Seven Galaxies indicating a small cluster of galaxies which would make them eligable for inclusion in the Hickson catalogue of compact groups. To put this into perspective, our Milky Way galaxy is a member of a local cluster of 34 galaxies.

Copeland's Septet is a close group of seven galaxies that lies about 480 million light-years away in Leo, discovered by Ralph Copeland in 1874 and the seventh member of Copeland's Septet is NGC 3754, a spiral galaxy (Members: NGC 3745, NGC 3746, NGC 3748, NGC 3750, NGC 3751, NGC 3753, NGC 3754).

[image: Copeland's Septet]

[image: NGC 3754: known locally as the Seventh Galaxy]

**NGC 3754: known locally as the Seventh Galaxy**

In 1982, the Canadian astronomer Paul Hickson, began compiling a catalogue of compact groups of galaxies which he had identified. These groups became known as the Hickson Compact Groups of galaxies, and Hickson published his list of 100 groups in his 'Atlas of Compact Groups of Galaxies.' In the first image showing Copeland's Septet, there is also "Hickson 57" to show the catalogue entry of this compact cluster.

It is unclear why the Kaleds  referred to their home galaxy as the Seventh Galaxy and not the "First" (or even a proper name) but it is possible that this just may be a quirk of the Tardis translation matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Out of interest, I came across the following from the "Dalek Book" (1964) which seems to place Skaro in our solar system
[image]

Comment: That Skaro seems to be in the solar system is discussed in https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Skaro